# Redirect www.domain.com/uk to www.domain.co.uk/uk

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internationalization, dns

I'm no `.htaccess` expert, but I've tried a few different things to redirect a domain to no avail.

I've got a UK and US domain...some US pages have uk extension, and need to be pointed to the proper UK domain:

`www.domain.com/uk` needs to be rewritten to `www.domain.co.uk/uk`

Ex. If someone types in `www.domain.com/uk/about` it will be rewritten as `www.domain.co.uk/uk/about`

**Edit**: Paths with `/uk` should be rewritten

So `www.domain.com/uk` and `www.domain.co.uk` should be rewritten to `www.domain.co.uk/uk/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The important point is to use a `RewriteCond`ition that works on the HTTP Host header. Simply speaking, if a `RewriteCond` is placed before a normal `RewriteRule` then the rule is only used if the the condition matches.

The code excerpt above redirects all requests from the `.COM` to the `.CO.UK` domain, so if you only need to redirect certain directory, then you need to adjust the rule accordingly, e.g.:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule uk(.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/uk$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Edit:** I hope that this will work for you according to your edit.

The first rule rewrites `http://www.domain.com/uk` and `http://www.domain.com/uk/anything` to `http://www.domain.co.uk/uk/anything`.

The second rule rewrites `http://www.domain.co.uk` to `http://www.domain.co.uk/uk/`.

**Edit 2:** I changed the rule (modified the last one and added another one) to reflect the demand for rewrites on `.co.uk/something`. If the path starts with `uk/` then it just passes through, otherwise it gets rewritten to `uk/something`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule uk($|/.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/uk$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^uk/(.*) - [PT,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your answer also needs to consider the that only paths starting with `/uk` should be redirected.

Comment: In my opinion, the original question is not quite clear about whether only paths should be redirected or files, too. It's mainly about domain redirects, but - sure - path-only redirects should be possible (with a different rule), too.

Comment: I've added an edit to my post, not sure if that clarifies anything.  /uk should always be there for a UK page

Comment: Hmm, I tried out the edit, the first rewrite rule works, but the second doesn't always. Let's say i type "www.domain.co.uk/about" it doesn't rewrite it as "www.domain.co.uk/uk/about"....but if i type just "www.domain.co.uk" it does rewrite it as "www.domain.co.uk/uk"

Comment: For that rewrite I've just modified the rule set (see Edit 2).